# Understanding the obscure template parameter of std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

The `std::function` has a template parameter:

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>
```

I am wondering, what type `R(Args...)` is, I think it is neither a **function pointer** `T`:

```
template<class R, typename... Args>
using T = R(*)(Args...);
```

nor a **function reference** `Q`:

```
template<class R, typename... Args>
using Q = R(&)(Args...);
```

So the type `P`

```
template<class R, typename... Args>
using P = R(Args...);
```

is simply a **function**.

And I can declare such a function and call it by:

```
int main(){
  P<int,int> myFunc;
  myFunc(3);
}
```

which will not compile since `myFunc` has never been defined.
If that is correct, where can I find more information about this type **function** in the standard?

Comment: Doesn't a signature of return type and parameter type list fully qualify a function signature? Captures are another piece of the pictures.

Comment: It's not "obscure". It's a template with a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: It's a great question. I've never seen the "call signature" specialisation documented anywhere. I picked it up as part of c++ lore many years ago. I'd love to know if there is a cppreference article on it or if it's mentioned in the standard

Comment: I think `R` is missing from your examples, that is it should be `template<typename R, typename... Args> using P = R(Args...);`

Comment: `P<int> myFunc;` declares a function returning an `int`, not taking one as a parameter. In other words, you would call it `myFunc()` instead of `myFunc(3)`.

Comment: Re: where in the standard. That would be [**\[dcl.fct\]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct)

Comment: `int f(int);` is a declaration of a function whose type is `int(int)`... in the same way that `int f[10]` is a declaration of an array whose type is `int[10]`

Comment: [Can confirm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e622b8bdb813f586) that it's just that R is missing.

Comment: @Barry: Thats I think the answer I am searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, the type is just a function type, which is a perfectly well-defined type in the C++ type system, defined in section 3.9.2 of the spec:

> 3.9.2 Compound types

> — functions, which have parameters of given types and return void or references or objects of a given type

The program:

```
template<class R, typename... Args>
using P = R(Args...);

int main(){
  P<int,int> myFunc;
  myFunc(3);
}
```

will *compile* just fine.  What it won't do is *link* -- you'll get an error like

```
prog.cpp:6: undefined reference to `myFunc(int)'
```

due to the fact that you've declared a function (and called it), but never defined it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function),

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>
```

is just the prototype of a std::function that takes a parameters pack `Args` as argument and return something of type `R`.

**Two simple examples**

- `std::function<const int&()> F([]{ return 42; });` takes no argument and return a `const int &`.

If you declare :

```
void print_num(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

- `std::function<void(int)> f_display = print_num;` takes an `int` and return nothing.